# Python http server for production

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, httpserver

Python docs claim, that "http.server is not recommended for production. It only implements basic security checks."

Is there another simple to use python server (like http.server) with "advanced" security check, ready for production?

(I want to run http server on Raspberri Pi, which will serve static website)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend something like Gunicorn or another WSGI Server.

https://gunicorn.org/

Furthermore there are some good hints for deployment of Python applications in the Flask documentation, which are not only applicable for Flask.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/

Comment: If you just want a simple static-page webserver and not a web app, Python must have *some* tool between "not recommended for production" and "full-fledged sledgehammer webapp framework".